# R: Using data.table and bigmemory to compensate for lack of memory size

Tags: r, performance, memory, time

I am working with the R programming language. I am trying to run the following code on my computer (I downscaled the number of observations so that it runs):

```
library(caret)
library(rpart)

#generate data

a = rnorm(1000, 10, 10)
b = rnorm(1000, 10, 5)
c = rnorm(1000, 5, 10)
group <- sample( LETTERS[1:2], 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5,0.5))
group_1 <- 1:1000

#put data into a frame
d = data.frame(a,b,c, group, group_1)
d$group = as.factor(d$group)

e <- d
vec1 <- sample(200:300, 5)
vec2 <- sample(400:500,5)
vec3 <- sample(700:800,5)
z <- 0
df <- expand.grid(vec1, vec2, vec3)
df$Accuracy <- NA

for (i in seq_along(vec1)) { 
  for (j in seq_along(vec2)) {
    for (k in seq_along(vec3)) {
      # d <- e
      d$group_2 = as.integer(ifelse(d$group_1 < vec1[i] , 0, ifelse(d$group_1 >vec1[i]  & d$group_1 < vec2[j] , 1, ifelse(d$group_1 >vec2[j]  & d$group_1 < vec3[k] , 2,3))))
      
      d$group_2 = as.factor(d$group_2)
      
      fitControl <- trainControl(## 10-fold CV
        method = "repeatedcv",
        number = 2,
        ## repeated ten times
        repeats = 1)
      
      TreeFit <- train(group_2 ~ ., data = d[,-5],
                       method = "rpart",
                       trControl = fitControl)
      
      pred <- predict(
        TreeFit,
        d[,-5])
      
      con <- confusionMatrix(
        d$group_2,
        pred) 
      
      #update results into table
      #final_table[i,j] = con$overall[1]
      z <- z + 1
      df$Accuracy[z] <- con$overall[1]
    }
  }
}
```

In reality, the "d" object that I am using in this procedure is very large - I left this procedure to run for several days and it never finished running. I did some research to find out whether this is happening because of "lack of memory". I saw that there are other libraries in R such as "data.table" and "bigmemory" that attempt to address similar problems. But I am not sure if these approaches are specifically meant for the kind of problem I am working on.

Could someone please show me if either "data.table" or "bigmemory" can be used to speed up the above procedure? If I were to convert "d" from a data frame to a "data.table", would this have any impact?

Thanks

Comment: If you profile your code, you'll see that most of the computation time is taken by `train()`. Not sure you can do anything about that.

Comment: thank you for your reply - these are the kind of comments i am interested in hearing.